# How to measure android internal/external storage random read speed programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I want to measure random read speed programmatically in my app to be sure that my app will work correctly on a particular device.

How can I do that in android?

Comment: by taking time difference using System.currentTimemillis() before and after the read!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar thanks a lot:) now we know you can measure. Any advice about random reading?